# Keras: No module named keras.models

Tags: python, keras

I've installed `keras 2.2.2` locally as well as `Theano 1.0.2`.  I've set `KERAS_BACKEND=theano` in my `.bash_profile` and sourced it.

I have a script with the line `from keras.models import load_model` in it and it errors out, telling me:

`ImportError: No module named keras.models`

However, when I do:

`python`
`from keras.models import load_model`

it succeeds.  I have the same version of Keras when I do `pip list` as when I check the Keras version in my Python interpreter.

Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: `python from keras.models import load_model` does nothing, but giving an error about missing file `from`

Comment: @lenik not sure what you mean.  could you elaborate?

Comment: you're telling us, that you get success running `python from keras.models import load_model` in a command line -- that does not really work that way.

Comment: @lenik I run `python` to get the python interpreter.  then I run `from keras.models import load_model`.  That works.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? If you are using a virtualenv, you may want to avoid using sudo. https://keras.io/#installation

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./learn_strokes_v1.py", line 78, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential               # Model type to be used
ImportError: No module named keras.models
```

and fixed this issue by using the below command

> pip install keras